# Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) :

Tags: r

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action,
>   xlev = object$xlevels) :

I put a numeric number instead of `NA` and I still get an error..

```
data$days_to_death[which(is.na(data$days_to_death))] <-5000

set.seed(1234)
tcontrol <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
modelKNN <- train(factor(tumor_stage) ~ ., data = trainset, method = "knn", preProcess = c("center", "scale"), trControl = tcontrol, na.action = na.omit)
modelKNN
validset$tumor_stage<-factor(validset$tumor_stage)

pKNN <- predict(modelKNN, validset)  ##This row gets the error
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) :

Comment: what comes after the ":" ?